# Can I get the contents of SHOW LOCKS as a table in Snowflake database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The command `SHOW LOCKS IN ACCOUNT` provides a relation of the locks of the form:

```
session resource type transaction transaction_started_on status acquired_on query_id
```

I want to get the same information in table form so that I can use `WHERE` conditions, something like:

```
select system$locks() where transaction_started_on > '2020-01-14 12:33:33';
```

I can't find any [function](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-all.html) that provides the locks or any view in [SNOWFLAKE.INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema.html#list-of-views) with this info. Is there any other way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use result scan to get a table of the show locks command.

```
    show locks in account myaccount;

    select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id())) where "transaction_started_on" > '2020-01-14 12:33:33';
```